# Chebyshev’s inequality?

Tags: probability

Any suggestions on how to prove that $$P(X \ge a) \le \frac{Var[X]}{Var[X]+(a-E[X])^2}$$ where X is a random variable and $a \gt E[X]$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as Cantelli's inequality. To show the proof, note that if $Y = X - E[X]$ then $P(Y \geq a-E[X])$ is equal to the LHS of the statement to be proved. Let $a - E[X] = b$ ,then $b > 0$.

For any $v \geq 0$, we have :
$$
P(Y \geq b) = P(Y + v \geq b + v) \leq P((Y+v)^2 \geq (b+v)^2)
$$

since the event $(Y+v \geq b+v)$ is contained in $((Y+v)^2 \geq (b+v)^2)$. Now, apply Markov's inequality to get $\frac{E[(Y+v)^2]}{(b+v)^2}$.

Your task : expand this expression, which applies for any $v \geq 0$, and then find the specific $v \geq 0$ which minimizes this expression. You can do this via calculus, and then the right hand side of Cantelli's inequality will emerge.

Answer (score -2):

Use Markovs inequality, with the function $f(x) = (x-E(x))^2$

Markovs inequality says that $

Comment: Isn't that the proof to Chebyshev’s inequality?

Comment: Applying Chebyshev's inequality will only give you $P(X \geq a) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{(a-E[X])^2}$, which is weaker than what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah i know, I've done the stronger version before but haven't got round to typing it up yet